# Replacing the playlist id in gdata playlist feed when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am using gdata playlist feed to grab all videos in the playlist to display it in my website.
Here is the JavaScript function which uses gdata playlist feed.I want to replace the playlist id with another playlist id when a link is clicked so that videos also gets replaced.

```
$(function() {
$('#ytVideoGallery').ytVideoGallery({
    feedUrl: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/9EA41FFD2282B969',
       playerOptions: {
        rel: '0',
        wmode: 'opaque'
       },
      playerWidth: 640,
      playerHeight: 360
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save options into a var.

```
   var options = {
    feedUrl: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/9EA41FFD2282B969',
       playerOptions: {
        rel: '0',
        wmode: 'opaque'
       },
      playerWidth: 640,
      playerHeight: 360
   };

$(function() {
  $('#ytVideoGallery').ytVideoGallery(options);
});
```

And after click you can append it to some another element:

```
$("#some_element").click(function(){
  $(this).ytVideoGallery(options);
  $('#ytVideoGallery').remove(); // You can remove previous element.
});
```